# What exactly is the math on the effects of having one off-sized wheel in an AWD?

Tags: tires, differential, awd

The internet is covered in dubious advice about replacing a single tire on an AWD.  I'd like to use some math instead.

What I suspect would be necessary is:

1. differences in tire sizes (easy)
2. rotations per mile (mile / circumference)
3. front/rear differential rotations per mile (size old/size new * rotations per mile)
4. differential rotation speed per mph (diff rotations per mile * mph)
5. some ability to find limits to how fast or how much a differential is okay to spin

Finding 1-4 is all seemingly pretty calculable.  #5 is hard.

As for finding those specifics and limits, I haven't been able to find any information on even ballpark estimates of how fast/much a differential can rotate before it gets worse.  Nor how much heat they can take.

**So it is possible to math this out?  Some logical way to tell how far/fast an AWD can go in a pinch?**

Comment: Before someone else comments it: always follow factory guidelines.

Comment: I'd say that this is more a question for our comrades in engineering.stackexchange.com

Comment: The problem is, you can't calculate #5 as a "one size fits all". There will always be a tolerance, but that tolerance is going to be different for every manufacturer. Subaru has a specification for their AWD system, yet Audi's specification is going to be different for theirs. IMHO, your comment says it all and is what should be used, *follow factory guidelines*. You are taking a long way around to an easy answer which really doesn't involve much math.

Comment: To expand a bit on @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 note here.  It also depends on the type of differential.  For example a standard gear-based diff will really not care about the different sizes since it just blindly spins.  A limited-slip differential, especially one that uses clutches may experience excess wear if the difference is too great.

Comment: Also, the larger issue here is not the differential, but the transfer case. It is what takes the punishment when there is a mismatch of tires.

Comment: Also, in electric and many partially electrified vehicles, the rear drive is all electric, with no mechanical connection to front drive, so this only applies to older vehicles. Electric rear drive doesn't at all care about tire size mismatch.

Comment: Furthermore, assuming you can drive 50 miles with the spare tire, it should at least temporarily tolerate very different rotation rates, unless the spare tire is a full-size one.

Comment: @Martin, you may be right.  It would seem that even a very loose measurement of what's happening is out of scope here.

Comment: The problem if we were to send this to engineering is, they'd reject it. If a question is ANYTHING about cars, they send it here or close it outright.

Comment: Ah.  I've had a few questions like this before.  Living enough in that grey area for a mod on either side to close it saying the other should be doing it.